# How to enter multiple records in single query in sql plus

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus, database-management

I have student table with 3 atributes STUDENT_ID, NAME and AGE

I'm getting this error after executing the query
Query:

```
INSERT INTO student(STUDENT_ID, NAME, AGE) 
values
(3, 'WILSON', 40),
(4, 'ALEX', 30);
```

Error:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Which database are you using? Add it in the tags.

Comment: INSERT INTO student(STUDENT_ID, NAME, AGE) 
values
(3, 'WILSON', 40);  INSERT INTO student(STUDENT_ID, NAME, AGE) 
values (4, 'ALEX', 30); /*  correct the syntax */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` and `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO student(STUDENT_ID, NAME, AGE) 
SELECT 3, 'WILSON', 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'ALEX', 30 FROM DUAL;
```